# What is the local variable for the C drive?

Tags: batch-file, local

There is a local variable for appdata, in C:\Windows, so what is the local variable for C:\?

Local variable for AppData - %APPDATA%

So what is the local variable for the C:\ Drive?

Comment: Why would there need to be a variable for a drive whose name you know? C: is C: always, like D: is D:. If you mean something logical and not the actual name, please edit the question and clarify

Comment: Type `SET` at a cmd prompt.

Comment: As an additinal note, your stated `%APPDATA%` variable is not specific to that location either, the default location, _which is by definition variable_, from, I think, Windows Vista is `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming`.

Comment: @Compo, the default `APPDATA` is relative to `USERPROFILE`.  A user's `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` aren't always configured as the user profile path (e.g. they could be a home directory on a network share), and sometimes they're not even defined. For example, they're not defined for a task scheduler batch logon. Also, if the user isn't already logged on interactively, the secondary logon service (used by runas.exe) sets them to `%SystemRoot%\System32`.

Comment: I don't disagree @eryksun, I specifically used the term 'default location' to mean 'is usually' whereas you specifically state 'aren't always'. In my experience the default locations for `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` and `%USERPROFILE%` match, the fact that they 'aren't always' was catered for in my term, '_which is by definition variable_'. I hope this has helped alleviate any misunderstanding.

Comment: The default location is [clearly defined](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457#FOLDERID_RoamingAppData) as `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming`. Programs should be using the API for this, but in cases where that's difficult (e.g. some scripting languages), they should use `APPDATA`, and use `USERPROFILE` for the default location for folders defined relative to the profile directory, and not `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH`. Note that nothing is defined relative to those variables.

Answer (score 4):

considering the lettering is arbitrary i'm going to assume you mean the system drive, in which case it would be `%SYSTEMDRIVE%`

if you're interested, the following is a good read, if a bit outdated:
http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/what-environment-variables-are-available-windows

EDIT: as noted in the comment, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows is a better source.